# Share JWT between an app and a browser on multiple subdomains

Tags: authentication, https, jwt, subdomain

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: schema]

Right now, the Desktop App, Auth server and API are working correctly, I can get my JWT and use it to call the API.

Both web apps are already in use, subdomain1.domain.com use NGINX auth_request, cookie and sessions on an old auth server to get access.

Web app in subdomain2.domain.com use session, and connect to the API with an app token.

And, all these servers are part of the same domain.

So, is it possible to share the JWT from my Desktop app with browsers? We generally use Chrome.
The desktop app use Python 3, and most of the user will be using Windows.

If I can't, and I'm pretty too stupid to do this working, my other concern is, can my browser use that JWT on all web app once it connected get it from auth server? All servers shares the same main domain.

Our web server can be using Apache2, Nginx, Nodejs or Flask (python), which is kind of annoying when trying to make things like that works.

I could use cookie for `.domain.com`, and store the jwt inside, am I right?
If yes, is this really the best idea?

The idea behind it is:

- User log in the app or browser
- JWT is generated
- JWT is shared between app and browser (not sure about this one)
- JWT is used on all subdomain by the browser

What is your advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a cookie in that case with no regrets. Just configure it correctly that every domains you need to have an access to this token.